# I got an error when trying to install a latex package trough tlmgr on ubuntu 20.04, verify_checksum: -5

Tags: 20.04, texlive

I installed texlive on ubuntu 20.04 with:

```
sudo apt -y install texlive-latex-extra texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils
```

when trying to install a latex package (any) i got:

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

any ideas?

EDIT: Hello, i install packages with `tlmgr install package_name`. tlmgr installs when installing latex...
Output of `dpkg -S $(which tlmgr)`

```
texlive-base: /usr/bin/tlmgr
```

Output of `apt-cache policy texlive-base`:

```
texlive-base:
  Installed: 2019.20200218-1
  Candidate: 2019.20200218-1
  Version table:
 *** 2019.20200218-1 500
        500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of `tlmgr --version`:

```
tlmgr revision 53568 (2020-01-27 19:20:16 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2019
```

Comment: How did you installed `tlmgr`? What is the output of `dpkg -S $(which tlmgr)` , `apt-cache policy texlive-base` and `tlmgr --version`? What do you mean by "trying to install a latex package"? How do you install such packages - from APT or from some archives?

Comment: I edited the question with the info requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two moments here:

1. According to [this Q&A on StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537379/183469) - the TuG GPG keys are expired, so you have to add `--verify-repo=none` to the command, like below:

   ```
   tlmgr --verify-repo=none install beamer
   ```

   Also please note that `tlmgr` will show the warning:

   > ```
   > tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
   > ```

   so some additional actions are required.
2. Personally I prefer to install using deb-packages from the distro. You can use such method as a workaround. For the *beamer* package the correct deb-package name may be obtained [from packages.ubuntu.com while searching for *beamer.cls*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=beamer.cls). So you have to install single package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
   ```

Comment: tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).

This error is solved changing the right repository for TexLive 2019.

Type this commands in a Terminal
```
tlmgr repository add ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
tlmgr repository list
tlmgr repository remove http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
```

Answer (score 0):

`tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020)`. This error is solved changing the right repository for TexLive 2019.

1. Type this commands in a Terminal to change de default repository

```bsh
tlmgr repository add tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
tlmgr repository list
tlmgr repository remove mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet 
tlmgr option repository tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
```

2. Install the LaTeX package you want using this:

```bsh
tlmgr --verify-repo=none install beamer
```

in this example I installed `beamer` package succesfully using the `--verify-repo=none` parameter.

Comment: As stated above, the `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended` will be easier and more reproducible. Bug if you use Ubuntu only on one machine, then tlmgr approach may be good for you.